# spark in yarn-cluser 'sc' not defined

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using spark 1.3.1.

Do I have to declare sc when spark run in yarn-cluster mode?  I have no problem running the same python program in spark python shell.

This is how I submit the job :

```
/bin/spark-submit --master yarn-cluster test.py --conf conf/spark-defaults.conf
```

where in spark-defaults I did declare where the `spark.yarn.jar` is, also check permission on where `spark.yarn.jar` is and `/user/admin`, the spark user, to make there is read-write-execute for all.

In my `test.py` program, I have `from pyspark.sql import SQLContext` and the first line is

```
sqlctx=SQLContext(sc)
```

and the error is

```
NameError: name 'sc' is not defined
```

on that line.

Any idea?

Comment: corrections with my post : tried this : ./bin/spark-submit --master yarn-cluster --conf spark.yarn.jar=hdfs://<aipaddres>:9000/share/spark-assembly-1.3.0-hadoop2.4.1.jar test.py ... also tried this ./bin/spark-submit --master yarn-cluster --conf conf/spark-defaults.conf  test.py

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 19):

This is what worked for me:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

conf = SparkConf().setAppName("building a warehouse")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlCtx = SQLContext(sc)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 11):

`sc` is a helper value created in the `spark-shell`, but is not automatically created with `spark-submit`. You must instantiate your own `SparkContext` and use that

```
conf = SparkConf().setAppName(appName)
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

Comment: thanks.  Then is my passing of "conf" parameter in the submit command is useless if I am creating another "conf"?

Comment: No, the conf file is used if nothing is set in the code. Also, if this helped you then don't forget to accept and upvote :)